# How to validate a custom data file with cloud-init

Tags: cloud-init

I am using custom-data to pass in some boot time configuration to a server on azure. I can see the file at the location

```
/var/lib/cloud/instances/<instance_id>/user-data.txt
```

and cloud-init is showing as done (cloud-init status)

the problem is that none of the script is doing anything, and there are no config files produced.

I was wondering if anyone knew of a command to show if the file at the location above is valid syntactically?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering if anyone knew of a command to show if the file at the location above is valid syntactically?

To validate the config, check out the cloud-init [schema](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/cli.html#schema) subcommand. Something like this may be what you want:

On a live system:

```bash
cloud-init schema --system
```

To see the userdata passed, try:

```bash
cloud-init query userdata
```

To see everything passed, try:

```bash
cloud-init query --all
```